# How can I access ALL model attributes from two tables joined together using django ORM

Tags: mysql, django, orm

I want to access all values from two related tables that I joined together based on one of the tables attributes:

```
obj = A.objects.filter(B__sample='sample_name').select_related()
```

but when i do:

```
{% for o in obj %}

    {{o.sample}}
    {{o.results}}
    {{o.qc}}

{% endfor %}
```

only o.results and o.qc (from table A) are returned, o.sample is not returned (from table B)

how do i access all of the values from table A and B from my queryset object?

Comment: post your models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misunderstood how models work in Django.

`sample` is an attribute from model B, and will always be that. Django won't ever add it as a direct attribute to model A; that would be confusing.

You still access it via an instance of model B; the magic that Django gives you is that `o.B` (or whatever your ForeignKey is called) will access that model B instance, so you can do `o.B.sample`. Since you've used `select_related`, that won't incur another database hit.

Answer (score 1):

```
obj = A.objects.filter(B__sample='sample_name').select_related('b')
```

try this , with small foreign model name